# Openstack instance network isn't working

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I created Centos 6 instance and network isn't accessible.

More specifically the `cloud-init` fails to connect to the metadata service at the system start/up giving the following error:

```
2015-04-10 21:24:04,448 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed [3/120s]: unexpected error ['ConnectionError' object has no attribute 'response']
```

Full boot log: http://pastebin.com/mTYU7N9E
Network topology: http://screencloud.net/v/d5OX
Please help!
I can provide additional another information.

Comment: Can you provide the neutron logs (probably `/var/log/neutron/...`) ? It may be a metadata-agent error and not a network error.

Comment: Also why did you assign the Instance to the public net work? I think is better to assign the private network to the Instance at the creation phase and then associate a public floating / public IP to it.

Comment: shouldn't need a public network to hit the metadata api.  that does seem indicative of a serious failure in the openstack environment configuration.